# Update Dataframe within While Loop Error: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays valid

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I cannot get the dataframe within the while loop to update. The while loop needs to run for the 6 values and update previous dataset with the previous value (remove oldest and add newest). Any help would be much appreciated.

```
# Multi-step forecast

# next_6days_stock_price 
validation_target = pd.to_numeric(['4185.47', '4163.26', '4134.94', '4173.42', '4134.98', '4180.17'], errors='coerce')
validation_predictions = []

#use the last 60 days to predict the next one into the future
#get the last 60 days close price and convert the dataframe to an array

#scale the data to be values between 0 and 1
a = data[['close']]
d = a[-n-1:]


while len(validation_predictions) < len(validation_target):   
  
  d['PrevClose'] = d['close'].shift(1)
  d['returns'] = (d['close'] - d['PrevClose']) / d['PrevClose']
  d['log_returns'] = np.log(1 + d['returns'])
  d = d[['close', 'log_returns']]
  
  last_m_d = scaler.transform(m)
  
  pred_price2 = model.predict(last_m_d.reshape(1, n, 2 )) # 2x1 array -> scalar
  pred_price2 = np.c_[pred_price2, np.zeros(pred_price2.shape)]
  pred_price2 = scaler.inverse_transform(pred_price2)
  pred_price2 = pred_price2[:1,0]
 
  # update the predictions list
  validation_predictions.append(pred_price2)
  p1 = np.array(validation_predictions)
  p1 = p1.reshape((p1.shape[0], -1), order='F')
  # make the new input
  d = np.roll(d, -1)
  d[-1] = pred_price2
```

Comment: You haven't shown us where the error occurs.  It looks like the kind of error produced when indexing a numpy array with a string.  Strings index dataframe columns, but not arrays derived from a frame.

Comment: The error occurs in the first four steps after the while loop. When I move these out of the while loop the code works but gives the same value 6 times. However, I need 6 different values where each output from the last run gets appended, one oldest value deleted and the code runs iteratively.

Comment: Looks like `d` is initially a `DataFrame` which accepts column names.  But in the `while` it changes to a `numpy` array, which does not work with names. Keeping track of your variable assignments and types is a basic part of Python debugging.

Comment: @hpaulj - I understand. How would you suggest I rectify this code please to get it to iterate without the error of changing its type within then loop to a numpy array?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but `np.roll` might be the problem.  Some `numpy` functions preserve the pandas dataframes, but not all.  That's the kind of thing your debugging should discover.

Comment: @hpaulj - I don't think that is the issue. the algorithm seems to work fine if I remove these steps from the code altogether:

Unfortunately I cannot remove them since I need to do those transformations. Any suggestion?

'''
  d['PrevClose'] = d['close'].shift(1)
  d['returns'] = (d['close'] - d['PrevClose']) / d['PrevClose']
  d['log_returns'] = np.log(1 + d['returns'])
  d = d[['close', 'log_returns']]

Comment: Add a `print(type(d))` at the start of the while loop.